# Database of all downloads

Tags: android, sql, database

Every Android device includes an application "Downloads". There we can see all recently downloaded files with source domains and the status of a particular download.

The question is where the list of downloads stored? I understand it's a kind of SQL DB. How can I access this DB from my application?

Thanks.

Comment: I found those places where downloads DB may be stored: com.sec.android.providers.downloads/databases/osisdownloads.db  and com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db. But even those two places are not universal. Galaxy Tab 2.3.5 still 'hides' the downloads....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every Android device includes an application "Downloads".

No, only on Android 2.3 and later.

> The question is where the list of downloads stored?

In the Downloads app's portion of internal storage.

> How can I access this DB from my application?

You don't. For your own downloads, use `DownloadManager.Query` to check on your download status. Data about downloads is not shared to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where the list of downloads is stored. But the downloaded files can often be found in a directory named Downloads in internal flash memory.

Comment: Not very helpful. What I really need is the URLs from which those downloads happen. Manually parsing downloads.db is possible but requires root.